# Codeblocks IDE C programming - doesn't come with libraries?

Tags: c, api, dll, codeblocks

I'm trying to create a C program in the CodeBlocks IDE (on Windows), and something I need is the library . When I try and build and run, this line errors:

```
#include <sys/times.h>
```

What do I do? Is that a Unix library? Can I download it and just add it somehow to my CodeBlocks environment? I mean,  is already there.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What function do you actually want to call? It may be provided by a different header or under a different name on Windows.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure because it's required for someone else's header file that I'm using.

Comment: Great, take out `#include <sys/times.h>` and see what breaks :)

Comment: The file I want to use is called "fcyc2.c", here: https://github.com/fabiensanglard/CpuCacheMountainViewer/blob/670141af7f32341f7e9e96bc999d1fa9163382c4/fcyc2.c

As you can see it uses sys/times.h as well as clock.h. The latter was included in the project, but I think everyone assumes your environment just has sys/times.h so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove -ansi compilation flag from `Settings` > `Compiler and Debugger` > `Compiler Options` in Code::Blocks. If that does not help, `<sys/times.h>` is unavailable under Windows.

**Edit**: `sys/times.h` is  a part of the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library) library. POSIX headers are not available under MinGW, and need Cygwin. [time.h](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/ansic-library.html) is a standard ANSI header. If you want to continue using `sys/times.h` on POSIX-compliant systems, what you could do instead to ensure portability is

```
#ifdef __WIN32__
# include <time.h>
#else
# include <sys/times.h>
#endif
```

Reference: [time.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do I remove that compilation flag in codeblocks?

Comment: `Settings` > `Compiler and Debugger` > `Compiler Options`

Comment: Thank you, I will go with time.h